ESP32 IDF WiFIMesh Functions esp_mesh_get_parent_bssid and esp_mesh_get_id
I am struggling to call "esp_mesh_get_parent_bssid"
At present I only have a single ESP32 board but the mesh network starts without errors and my ESP32 as the root tests successfully with MQTT messages.
mesh_addr_t meshParentAddr;
esp_mesh_get_parent_bssid(&meshParentAddr);
ESP_LOGI(MESH_TAG, "Mesh Parent IP: " IPSTR ": %d  MAC: " MACSTR "", IP2STR(&mesh_parent_addr.mip.ip4), mesh_parent_addr.mip.port, MAC2STR(mesh_parent_addr.addr));

My output gives me:
I (16:10:30.729) mesh_main: Mesh Parent IP: 92.233.49.154: 6749  MAC: 5c:e9:31:9a:5d:1a

The IP and Port don't look correct to me as my WiFi router has an IP address of 192.168.1.1
The reported MAC is correct.
I have a similar problem calling:
mesh_addr_t meshAddr = {};
esp_mesh_get_id(&meshAddr);

But with this call the IP4 address and MAC are both wrong.
Thanks for your help

does your router/AP support esp32 mesh network? I doubt that it does

Thanks for your response. I guess I expected the ESP32 Root node would still be able to get and report my routers IP address.  But in any case I have the same problem with esp_mesh_get_id which is designed to return the root node (ESP32) own IP address and MAC
